# GPRS Application using Java

Tags: java, gprs

> We developed application written in Java/J2EE using which send and receives SMS from service provider and presently we are facing problem that there is some delay in messages and it cost's more for us.

by considering above situation we planned to move to GPRS technology (which is more cheaper and considerably fast).

So please suggest a course of action I can start with and post any sample application for GPRS-enabled system in Java.

Comment: How you planned to use GPRS without knowing how it works in your setup?

Answer (score 1):

With GPRS you would need a client application running in the mobile device. This means a lot of headaches for developing, deploying and supporting. Also, although it would be trivial for the clients to send messages, receiving won't be so straightforward. You would need to implement some kind of a "push" service. One of the problems would be that the client application should be always running.

In general, it isn't easy to replace SMS messages with GPRS communication. You may need to considerably change the architecture of your system.

Answer (score 1):

To make a GPRS application using java you have to need GPRS Modem. First of all you have to make one container which handle request and replay of GPRS modem and your API. API contain private ip and port number wich send the request to container and container then send request to modelm and modem will give response to container and it send back to API.

By using methd Socket("IP Address", port number) you can connect with container and modem .

You have to need a public Ip Address andPort Number, it create virtual pipline between modem and container like as a telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Using GPRS instead of GSM to send an SMS *will not* cause the SMS to be delivered any faster. You're barking up the wrong tree.